# Nested list and dictionary efficiency

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I'm working on a project that requires a 2D map with a list for every possible x and y coordinate on that map. Seeing as though the map dimensions are constant, which is faster for creation, searching and changing values of?

Let's say that I have a 2x2 grid with a total of 4 positions. Each stores 2-bits (0, 1, 2 or 3) would having "[0b00, 0b00, 0b00, 0b01]" represent the list be better than "[[0b00, 0b00], [0b00, 0b01]]" in terms of efficiency and readability?

I assumed that the first method would be quicker at creation and iterating over all of the values but the second be faster for finding the value of a certain position (so listName[1][0] is easier to work out than listName[2]).

To clarify, I want to know what is both more memory efficient and CPU efficient for the 3 listed uses and (if it isn't too much trouble) why they are so. Further, the actual lists I'm using are 4096x4096 (using a total of 17Mb in raw data).

Note: I DO already plan on splitting the 4096x4096 grid into sectors that will be part of a nested list, I'm just asking if x and y should be on the same nesting level.

Thanks.

Comment: for me, sys.getsizeof([0b00, 0b00, 0b00, 0b01]) =  96 and

sys.getsizeof([[0b00, 0b00], [0b00, 0b01]]) =  80

so, there's that.

Comment: K, thank you. You have no idea how many times I've used that function in the past few weeks... 24-byte integers! Wow... Granted though, Python integers CAN be as many bits long as you have RAM in your computer (I've been looking at the C code for Python Integers).